# Running Huge Process for every user in a web application server

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework-2.0, cluster-computing, application-server

We are building a web portal based application with html5/javascript frontend and Play framework backend with mongodb.

I am an algorithm developer from the networking industry, we have to do design analysis of networks. This is done by complex algorithms in standalone java based application today. We are planning to move this standalone logic to the play application server with user logic and session management.

This would mean, we would have huge object cache and processing requirement everytime a user asks for analysis and we are planning for a 100+ user simultaneously. There is also lot of static data present today in the java cache model of the standalone application.

I am new to application server space, many people suggested that web application servers are not meant to manage this kind of usecase and the object cache is meant for volume query on a db and simpler rendering of db data, rather than running algorithms on it.

Question I have are :

- Can Play or any other web application server manage such processing need?
- Is there any design recommendation to convert heavy java based stand-alone tools to web-based, business logic and session managed and db persisted environment?

Comment: You could have a web application server just for managing users and analysis requests, while actually running your algorithms in a Hadoop cluster.

Comment: Yes but the problem we have is, we need a centralized java object cache, which would be huge. This cache should be namespaced for local data based on user session and global static data (like configs, pricelist) which will be accessible to all and immutable. I was planning to have the object cache in play itself, but many are telling me its a bad idea